# Cannot convert method group 'EmIsNull' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Tags: c#

```
public static class MyExtention
{
    public static bool EmIsNull<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return (obj == null);
    }
}
```

// usage in main class

```
if(dataGridView1["IP", i].Value.EmIsNull)
```

//then get error message

Error   1:  Cannot convert method group 'EmIsNull' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the function brackets `()` at the end.

```
if(dataGridView1["IP", i].Value.EmIsNull())
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as its a method , and in if condition you need to mention use function brackets ().

See the below example

```
private bool Validation()
        { 
         foreach ( RadioButton rbtn in filetypepnl.Controls)
         {
         if(rbtn.Checked)
         {
             return true;
         }
         }
         return false;
        }
```

To Use

```
if(Validation())
 {
   if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){ }
 }
```